# gethostbyname() and gethostbyaddr() returning different host names?

Tags: c, networking, gethostbyname, gethostbyaddr

`gethostbyname()` and `gethostbyaddr()` are both returning different h_name values in their returned `hostent structs` when I call them in my program. I'm wondering if this behaviour is normal or should the two return identical host names?

Comment: Q: What are the values?  Are they both valid?

Comment: @paulsm4 For example, when I run it on "www.wwe.com" I get "wwe.com" as the host. But when I use their IP Address "54.236.192.188" I get "ec2-54-236-192-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com" as the host name. Is the error in my coding? Or is this just a problem with these functions?

Comment: This is normal, a host may have many names.